# State of the art on strong full exceptional collections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I am trying to understand on which kinds of varieties we can find *strong* full exceptional collections of sheaves. (Classical examples are of course projective spaces (Beilinson) and Grassmann varieties and quadrics (Kapranov).)

As far as I understand, the "strongness" of an exceptional collection implies that the derived category of coherent sheaves is equivalent to the derived category of modules over an *associative* algebra.

If one is content with working with DG algebras one can just focus on exceptional collections, while allowing higher Ext groups between the sheaves in the collection. However, I would like to know what currently is known about varieties with *strong* exceptional collections.